# Websphere tries to load app that is removed

Tags: websphere, rsa

I am using Websphere 6.1.33 with RSA7.0. I am deploying my app through RSA and not through admin console.
I removed the app by 'Add and Remove projects'. But now when the server starts, it still tried to load the app. I can see console messages like 'Loading web module for appname'.

Of course the app is not there and it hangs.
The only crime I did was to delete the wstemp and temp directories but surely that cannot be the problem?

How can I troubleshoot? Why is it still looking for the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is WebSphere running when you delete delete the wstemp/temp directories?  In my experience, it's safe to clean out those directories when the server is stopped, but not while it's running.

I use RAD instead of RSA, but I've experienced the same thing on occasion.  When that happens, I log in to the admin console and uninstall the application in the "Enterprise Applications" section.  Then I install the application again in RAD using the "Add and Remove projects" function.